# How should I go about demonstrating Ubuntu on someone else's system?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

My relative saw me using Ubuntu and asked me about it. I suggested him to try it. He asked me to show it in his pc, to try it.

I recommended him to use the Live USB stick and try with it or install it as an app in windows. I have an Windows 7 pc as his is an Windows XP so I don't want to take any risks, if something goes wrong I'll be blamed!

These are the system specifications:

1. **Operating System:** Microsoft Windows XP Professional 32-bit SP2
2. **CPU:** Intel Pentium E5700 @ 3.00GHz
3. **RAM:** 2.00 GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 399MHz
4. **Motherboard:** Intel Corporation DG41RQ (J2E1)
5. **Graphics:** E2041 (1280x720@60Hz), Intel G41 Express Chipset
6. **Hard Drives:** 233GB Seagate ST250DM000-1BD141 (SATA)

So how do I go about doing it , He has few PCs to run at office and at home. So which version of Ubuntu would suite him and which would be the best way to let him try it (live USB or as an application or otherwise)?

Please help me, and explain the process in detail.

Comment: Thanks for using this site. Exactly, what kind of suggestion are you seeking? Perhaps, are you asking what is the "best" installation method (Live USB versus Live DVD versus Wubi)? If so, what is your definition of _best installation method_?

Comment: @ =Andrea Corbellini                                                  Best installation method includes not touching XP or any other softwares as in my pc when i installed ubuntu my windows 7 boot partitioner crashed i want nothing like that to happen. I also want to know which is safe for XP.WHich would be fast in xp and......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am dual booting Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32 bit) and Windows XP (32 bit) and both the OS's run perfectly fine on my system.I would recommend you also to install Ubuntu 12.04LTS (32 bit) using a Bootable USB on Separate partion. I had followed this [link](http://www.sinarpelangi.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-for-newbies/) to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my system.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Live USB, Ubuntu 12.04 and just let him try it out on a Live USB and then install it.

What was your concern?

Comment: My concern was when trying with Live USB the performance would be slower, and he may not experience the power of ubuntu.

Comment: @G.Ashwinkumar it's a bit slower, but if you get comments about it being slow just install it on a small partition and show how fast it is. But a live USB shows also how easy it is to use Ubuntu, so I would still recommend it.